# Get start and end ranges from a sequence containing gaps

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data:

```
c(1:4,7:15,20:23,25,30:35,40,41)
```

I want to get the start and end ranges from that vector. Yet, I want to skip single values, that have no natural predecessor and successor (in the example: 25). In other words, there should be at least two consecutive values to make a "range".

The start ranges in this example are: `1, 7, 20, 30, 40`
Their corresponding end ranges are: `4, 15, 23, 35, 41`

Is there any elegant built-in solution? I am pretty much stuck in a for loop hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify locations where `diff(x)` is > 1, lagged appropriately by adding `TRUE` to the beginning or end of the sequence. (`diff(x)` produces a vector that is one element shorter than `x`.) The `&` clauses get rid of the singleton values.

```r
dx1 <- c(TRUE,diff(x)>1)
dx2 <- c(diff(x)>1, TRUE)
start <- x[dx1 & !dx2]
end <-   x[dx2 & !dx1]
```

There is probably also a solution with something like `rle(diff(x)==1)`, but it would be a little more complicated than the solution above (it might be useful if e.g. you wanted to identify runs of a particular length).

Comment: Oh my god! You nailed it in 4 lines of code... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't add much to the solution from @Ben Bolker, but another way could be:

```
ind <- aggregate(x ~ cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x)) > 1), FUN = function(x) (length(x) > 1) * range(x))
ind$x[ind$x[, 1] != 0, ]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    7   15
[3,]   20   23
[4,]   30   35
[5,]   40   41
```